# Invalid Syntax Python?

Tags: python

Why is this code wrong (from Python 3.3.2). All it outputs is 'invalid syntax' when I've looked over the code lots of times:

```
#Get the numbers from the useer
a = int(input("Enter number a: "))
b = int(input("Enter number b: "))
c = int(input("Enter number c: "))

d = a*b*c #Make d a times b times c

#Display the results
print (str(a) + " mutiplied by " + str(b) + "multiplied by" + str(c) " equals " + str(d)))
```

This is what it should output:

*Enter number a: 5*

*Enter number b: 10*

*Enter number c: 3*

*5 multiplied by 10 multiplied by 3 equals 150*

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is one of the reasons that string concatenation using the `+` operator is discouraged.  Use python string formatting instead:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: Always show the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a `+` operator in that last line, and you have an extra close paren at the end of that line.

```
print (str(a) + " mutiplied by " + str(b) + "multiplied by" + str(c) " equals " + str(d)))
                                                                   ^^^                  ^^^
```

Comment: It works! Silly me! Now I'll have to adjust the output so that it looks more like a sentence.

Comment: It's ok, it comes with practice.  Also, you should learn to look closely at the stuff your interpreter outputs with each error - it's designed to help you debug.  It will often show you with little carets `^` where the error is.

Comment: It didn't show the error on my computer because a window came up and said 'Invalid syntax'. It didn't say anything in the console.

Comment: Ok - it depends on what environment you're using.  I would be surprised if that info (called a stack trace) isn't available somewhere.